# Magento 1.7 Redirect on review_product_view Page

Tags: magento-1.7, php, event-observer, redirect

I have 3 observers set up that execute a 301 redirect via this method:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()
  ->setRedirect($url, 301)
  ->sendResponse();
```

2 of the observer events execute the redirect perfectly but the 3rd one does not. I tested to ensure that my 'if' conditions are all met and the redirect function is called but it seems that the redirect is simply ignored on the last observer. Here are my events:

```
controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view - 301 redirect works
controller_action_predispatch_review_product_list - 301 redirect works
controller_action_predispatch_review_product_view - 301 redirect ignored
```

I took a look at the controller and couldn't determine whats preventing the 301 redirect from working on `controller_action_predispatch_review_product_view`. I also use Alan Storm's Commerce Bug 2 and went through the useful list of events that his module includes. Something  in the `Mage_Review_ProductController` must be preventing the function from working but I cant put my finger on it. Please help...Thank you!

```
<events>
  <controller_action_predispatch_review_product_view>
    <observers>
      <commerceextensions_groupedproductredirect_observer>
        <class>CommerceExtensions_GroupedProductRedirect_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>redirectReviewView</method>
      </commerceextensions_groupedproductredirect_observer>
    </observers>
  </controller_action_predispatch_review_product_view>            
</events>
```

The redirect part of this function does get reached, I have verified it many times.

```
  public function redirectReviewView($observer)
  {
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('groupedproductredirect/active/overall')){
      $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
      $productId = Mage::getModel('review/review')->load($id)->getEntityPkValue(); // get product id
      $product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); // load the product   
      if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && $product->getVisibility() == 1){
        $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
        if(!empty($parentIds)){ 
          $parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]); 
          if(Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('CommerceExtensions_BetterReviews')->is('active', 'true')){ // IF BETTERREVIEWS EXTENSION INSTALLED   
            if(Mage::getStoreConfig('productpagereviews/active/overall')){ // IF PRODUCTPAGEREVIEWS IS ENABLED            
              // go the product page reviews section of the parent grouped product            
              $url = $parentProduct->getProductUrl().'#customer-reviews';  
            } else { // IF PRODUCTPAGEREVIEWS IS NOT ENABLED
              // go the reviews page of the parent grouped product
              $url = Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array('id'=> $parentProduct->getId()));  
            }                   
          } else {// IF BETTERREVIEWS EXTENSION IS NOT INSTALLED
            // go the reviews page of the parent grouped product
            $url = Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array('id'=> $parentProduct->getId()));
          }
          Mage::app()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url, 301)
            ->sendResponse();                 
        }               
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you tried putting an `exit();` after the redirect code?

Comment: i have, its completely ignored unfortunately.

Comment: sounds like the script never reaches that point. The only other thing I can think of is the headers already being sent preventing the redirect

Comment: it it definitely getting there, its just being ignored.

Comment: and using a plain `header('location: '.$url);`, does that work?

Comment: I hadnt tried doing it that way. The more I work with Magento, the more I realize that there is a built in method to do almost everything. I will give your method a try though and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: can you post the `config.xml` section for your observer for `controller_action_predispatch_review_product_view`?

Comment: Hi Marius, I have added the config xml as well as the function I use. I use this same code to redirect review_product_list and catalog_product_view and they work great. Its just this one that wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong or customized in your install; I've tested your approach and it should work fine. You could test for sure using the scoped postdispatch event.

However, depending on configuration, you *should* terminate execution after sending the response, otherwise the `\Mage_Review_ProductController::preDispatch()` method may set additional headers:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();

    $allowGuest = Mage::helper('review')->getIsGuestAllowToWrite();
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
        return;
    }

    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if (!$allowGuest && $action == 'post' && $this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true)));
            Mage::getSingleton('review/session')->setFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                ->setRedirectUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
            $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Based on your advice, I added an exit; just after the redirect. There must have been headers being set elsewhere in the site, so this worked like a charm. Thanks!